# Rails 5.1.5: lambda with two params for JSONB column data filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, lambda

I have `position_positions` table with JSONB column named `data`. I'm a bit stuck with my lambda, which should do filtering by `ptype` value of that `data` column.

My method where I have lambda with two params (this is mandatory) looks like this:

```
def find_ptype
  -> (column, formated_value) { 
    where("position_positions.data->>'ptype' = ?", "#{formated_value}%")
  }
end
```

however I get this error: `NoMethodError (undefined method "where" for #`

Another atempt was with Arel:

```
def find_ptype
  ->(column, formatted_value) {
    Arel.sql("JSON_EXTRACT(#{column.field}, '$.ptype') = '#{formatted_value}'")
  }
end
```

but I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function json_extract(text, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ND "position_positions"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (JSON_EXTRA...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "position_positions" WHERE "position_positions"."type" IN ('Position::Outdoor') AND "position_positions"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (JSON_EXTRACT(data->>'ptype', '$.ptype') = 'billboard')):
```

In this example above I'm trying to pass in `billboard` value for my `data->>'ptype'`, but got that error.

**How can I fix my method to do filtering for my JSONB column values, please?** I'll be happy for any hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Below code may help you.

```
def find_ptype
  -> (column, formated_value) { 
    where("position_positions.data->>'ptype' = ?", "%#{formated_value}%")
  }
end
```

You missed opening %. That is causing the above issue.

[JSON and JSONB](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb)

I run your code and found it is not working fine.

```
def find_ptype
    -> (column, formated_value) { 
      # where("position_positions.data->>'ptype' = ?", "%#{formated_value}%")
      where("payload->>'kind' = ?", "%#{formated_value}%")
    }
  end
```

It is showing below error:

[image: Error]

Upon replacing above code with below one working fine.

```
scope :find_ptype, ->(column, formated_value){ 
    where("payload->>'kind' LIKE ?", "%#{formated_value}%")
  }
```

And output is:

[image: Output]

[image: Final Output]

Comment: Thank you, however I keep getting same error: `NoMethodError (undefined method "where" for #`

Answer (score 1):

My case was related to [ajax-datatables-rails gem](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/277) and it seems this is the solution:

```
def find_ptype
 ->(column, formated_value) {
   Arel.sql("position_positions.#{column.field} = '#{formated_value}'")
 }
end
```

As I'm passing in my `data->>'ptype'` as column and `billboard` as `formated_value` I needed to add `position_positions` table and remove `JSON_EXTRACT` part.

I hope this helps someone else, who's trying to implement search by JSONB column values.